# Is there any way to implement a custom button with more than 2 images?

Tags: android, image, button

is there any way to implement a custom button with more than 2 images? (pressed and unpressed), I want to make, for exameple, 5 o 6 progressive images of state pressed, and same with unpressed, so the final look is that this button will be more smooth animation.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a Transition Drawable. These can be defined in XML, see here: [Transition Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Transition)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look as soon as possible. ;)